# Can a Catholic diocese hold onto money raised by a parish for parish refurbishments?

Tags: catholicism, money, church-finance

If a Catholic Parish specifically raises money for the parish - say refurbishment of its church hall kitchen- can the Diocese hold onto the money for as long as it says it needs it?
The parishioners are upset and want to put any future money raised for the refurbishment into a new separate bank account controlled by the Parish Finance committee!